# Not understanding classes and usage

Tags: c#, winforms, oop

Not understanding classes and usage

I have a VS2010 project, This project has a number of classes (sub projects in the Project)
I am trying to use a method in the class as I would in a local winforms project 
IE

```
   using System.Diagnostics;

   namespace DataBaseAccess
   {
          public class Class1
          {
               string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("names.txt");

               public string startgenerationofnames()
               {
                  foreach (string value in lines)
                  {
                     Debug.WriteLine(lines);
                     //call next class with the current value
                  }
               }
         }
   }
```

I would like to use this class from winforms, I have created the class.

```
DataBaseAccess.Class1 makenames = new DataBaseAccess.Class1();
```

and would like to use it like I would in a normal way as I would if there was no class
IE

```
 DataBaseAccess.Class1.startgenerationofnames();
```

I am not expecting return values, nor am I expecting anything from the class, other then to run the Debug.WriteLine(lines);
I am obviosly failing to understand this basic task and have been searching for it for days already.
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your method and class to be static to call the method without needing an instance of the class.

```
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace DataBaseAccess
{
    public static class Class1
    {
        private static string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("names.txt");

        public static void startgenerationofnames()
        {
            foreach (string value in lines)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(lines);
                //call next class with the current value
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can invoke it like this:

```
DataBaseAccess.Class1.startgenerationofnames();
```

Comment: Won't compile and it isn't necessary for the class to be static in order to have static methods.

Comment: Be careful: you cannot use `lines` inside a static method because `lines` is not static. Am I right?

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth - I know, but conventional knowledge is that when a class will only have static methods, it is better to make the class static to document its intention.

Comment: @Marco - Yes, I updated my code to reflect this.  Made lines static.

Answer (score 0):

Create your class as static class and static method. Then you can call the method without instantiating the class.

Comment: Making the class static isn't necessary for containing static methods.

Comment: I made the class static, but now from the winform how do I call it? intellisence does not show anything when I try to create the class

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth - True, but the OP says that is the only way the class would be used so it is better convention to make it a static class to document its intention.

Comment: @j0rd4n agreed, however, the answer doesn't state that and makes it sound like a static class is required for static methods, hence my comment.

Comment: If the class and windows form is in the same namespace you would just call the class as Class1.startgenerationofnames(); if it is not in the same namespace it would be DataBaseAccess.Class1.startgenerationofnames(); I can also see that your return type is string and you are currently not returning any string values? Also we are assuming that your class is in the same project, if not you would have to add a project reference to it.

Answer (score 0):

You could define `public string startgenerationofnames()` to use it without instantiating Class1, but in this case this fails because you're using (inside `startgenerationofnames`) variables that are not static.
You could use:

```
public class Class1
{
    static string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("names.txt");
    public static string startgenerationofnames()
    {
        foreach (string value in lines)
        {
             Debug.WriteLine(line); // not lines
             //call next class with the current value
        }
        return ""; // or what you need
     }
}
```

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth: yes, Ive just edited my answer. Anyway my example wanted to show OP how he can call this method without a class instance. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things... 1 your startgenerationofnames needs to return a string... or you could change it to a void return type.

2 move the loading of the read all lines into the function itself... you don't want to do anything like that as part of the object construction... because it will give you an error that is less obvious to what is wrong.

Try this...

```
 public static class Class1
                {

           public static void startgenerationofnames()
          {
               string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("names.txt");
               foreach (string value in lines)
              {
                Debug.WriteLine(lines);
                //call next class with the current value
              }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to make the class static, just the method.  However, you cannot do this currently as your method uses instance members of the class:

`string[] lines ...`

A standard static definition of a method includes the `static` keyword:

`public static string startgenerationofnames()`

I think you want no return (?), and you need to move the lines into the method (or make them static in the class):

```
public static void StartGenerationOfNames()
{
    string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("names.txt");

    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(line);
    }
}
```

If you don't want the class to be instantiated at all, you can make the class itself static:

`public static class Class1`

This then forces any members inside the class to be static and stops people from being able to instantiate it via:

`Class1 c = new Class1();`

Usage of the class is as you'd expect with static methods:

`Class1.StartGenerationOfNames();`